# restrict access based on SSH key

Tags: shell, unix, authentication, ssh, permissions

Say, I have an account on my remote server `storage` where uses can upload and download data from. I add the SSH key of the allowed users manually to `/home/storage/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Now, I have two users that use different public SSH keys, Watson and Sherlock.

How can I make sure that Watson can not upload to/download from Sherlocks private gallery? Is it possible to define file/folder permission based on the SSH key that was used to authenticate?

I thought about a restricted shell program that is set as the `storage` user's shell. But how can this restricted shell find out what SSH key was used?

Comment: If you don't want them to share permissions then don't share a user account. If you *need* to share a user account you can look at what `gitolite` does for this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the `command` option in the `/home/storage/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, with a restricted shell, like this:

```
command="cd /home/storage/watson && rbash" ssh-rsa AAAAB3...2Z <- watson's public key
command="cd /home/storage/sherlock && rbash" ssh-rsa AAAAB4...R5 <- sherlock's public key
```

Now the user will get a restricted shell in a subdirectory depending on which private key is used.