# How to restrict git SSH access based on ssh key given

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a private git server with one user `git` and ssh key authentication. Currently, I am the only one using it, but I want to add more people and I want everyone to use user `git` to connect to the server and perform `git clone`, `git push`, etc. If all the repositories are "public", then I know how to solve this. But for example I want to have a private repository, that I will still clone via `git clone git@server:repo` with my SSH key, however I do not want other users to be able to clone it using their SSH keys.

I checked git-scm documentation on setting up the server (which was helpful for public repositories), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914841/restrict-access-based-on-ssh-key) post, however this post seems to only solve the problem for only private repositories.

TLDR: When you clone a repository on GitHub, you say `git clone git@github.com:user/repo` and your git username and ssh key are being sent over. Now, depending on whether you have the permissions to this repository, you can clone it, otherwise not. So basically, everyone is using `git` user on the surface, but under the hood some authorisation is taking place. How does GitHub handle this for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gitolite`](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/) seems to be exactly what you are looking for managing access to repositories/branches based on the ssh key.

But if you want to build something like this from scratch you need to look into the options in the `authorized_keys` file, especially [`command`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#command=_command_) and [`environment`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#environment=_NAME=value_). With these you can force a specific command/script or add/overwrite environment variables based on which ssh key was used.

For example you could write a script that reads the allowed repositories for the user as its arguments and force it to be run for selected ssh keys:

```bash
# file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="/home/git/bin/git-only-shell /home/git/repos/repo1" ssh-rsa AAAAB2...
command="/home/git/bin/git-only-shell /home/git/repos/repo1 /home/git/repos/repo2" ssh-rsa AAAAB3...
```

The script can now read the requested repo from `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` and check that it is contained in the passed list. A complete - but crude - example implementation of this script `git-only-shell` could be like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# verify that $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND starts with git-upload-pack, git-upload-archive or
# git-receive-pack, followed by a space
if ! [[ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" == git-upload-pack\ * || "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" == git-upload-archive\ * || "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" == git-receive-pack\ * ]]; then
    echo "unsupported command" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# remove first word (git command)
ARGUMENTS="${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND#git-* }"

# use eval to un-quote repo path (it is passed in single-quotes)
REPO_PATH="$(eval "echo $ARGUMENTS")"

# allowed repos are passed as arguments to this script
ALLOWED_REPOS=("$@")

# check if repo was whitelisted
IS_ALLOWED=false
for repo in "${ALLOWED_REPOS[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$REPO_PATH" == "$repo" ]]; then
        IS_ALLOWED=true
    fi
done

if [[ $IS_ALLOWED == "false" ]]; then
    echo "access to this repo not allowed" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# execute the original command
eval "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, thanks! I will test this and if it suffices me, I will accept your answer.

Comment: `eval "echo $ARGUMENTS"` is dangerous for command injection and CRE vulnerability.

Comment: Probably [switch the local variables to lower case to avoid name clashes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1):

To implement a similar feature, you could rely on a dedicated tool such as [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html).

Otherwise, you could install a full-blown [GitLab server](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/) which would also provide fine-grained access control to the repositories, with "Git URLs" such as `git@your-gitlab-domain.com:user/repo.git`

(BTW it seems GitLab formerly relied on `gitolite`, [before version 5.0.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/changelogs/archive.md#anchor-500))

Comment: I do not want to rely on GitLab, because I want to basically build GitHub / GitLab from scratch. I've taken a look at gitolite but couldn't find a solution yet. I guess I will need to dive deeper into it.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like `gitolite` were too complicated and unpleasant to use or did not offer the desired features. I ended up with the following solution:

- A PostgreSQL database with tables `user` and `repo`, and a many-to-many table `permissions`.
- A program written in C that checks whether a user has read/write permissions to access requested repository, which is extracted from `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.
- In `.ssh/authorized_keys`, each key has its own `command` which calls a C program with the username associated with that key and a repository extracted from SSH command when that key is used for `git` operations.

So, when a user adds an SSH key to his account, a line in `.ssh/authorized_keys` is added, e.g.

```sh
command="/home/git/check_perms username \"${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}\"" no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ...
```

Then the `command` is run every time a Git operation is performed using this key. If a user does not have sufficient permissions, the Git operation is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using [git-shell](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) and a little bit of bash. The general idea is to check whether the key'd user is supposed to access a given repository, and if so, running their command with `git-shell`.

The shell script is as follows;

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND=${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND#git-}
a=( ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND//\'/} ) # strip single qoutes [^1]

cmd=${a[0]} # git * command
path=${a[-1]} # targeted path
unset a[0] a[-1]

# optional arguments
if (( ${#a[@]} )); then
    args="#{a[*]} "
fi

# check if the target path is whitelisted
for a_path in $@; do
    f_path="${a_path}${path#@(a_path/|../)}/" # f(ull)_path
    if [ -d "$f_path" ]; then
        /path/to/git-shell -c "git $cmd $args'$f_path'"
    fi
done
```

We then modify the git user's `.ssh/authorized_keys`;

```
command="/path/to/script /foo/ /bar/ /biz/" ssh-...
```

### Attacks

Arbitrary command execution is prevented by exlusively using `git-shell`, so we only have to worry about access to unauthorised repositories -- this is addressed in two ways;

- Removing instances of `../` when composing `f_path`.
- Scoping the targeted path when checking for directory existence.

e.g.;

```
 - foo     [Authorised]
 |_ biz
 - bar
 |_ boo

====
- `git clone git@server.dom:foo/../bar/boo` fails
- `git clone git@server.dom:bar` fails
- `git clone git@server.dom:foo/biz` passes
```

### References

[1]: The way that `a` is formed here may not play nice with globing; see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212526/12039300) for more context.